Why is there a 2 weeks break between Olympic and Paralympic Games?
I just noticed that there is a 2 weeks gap between the Olympic and Paralympic Games (the former ends on 2024-08-11 and the latter starts on 2024-08-24).
I can imagine that the participants' rooms need to be cleaned but this could be done in a day or two.
On the other hand, you have the whole logistics (including people) who will need to be put on hold. It is also quite counter-productive from a supporter participation aspect: August is vacation time and something happening in early September will clash with everyday life.
Is there a specific reason for this break?

August is only "vacation time" for very specific people and countries. The Olympics are international. I would not expect them to make decisions based purely or even primarily on spectator availability.

@Nij: I realize that but in France where the 2024 OG are held, August is ideal for many reasons (early September is the worst possible choice). In addition, the gap breaks a lot of logistics, people deployment etc. I was wondering if there is an announced reason for that gap instead of chaining them up (leaving, say, 2 days for cleanup of the  participants' rooms)

Again, spectators are not a primary concern at all. The TV market is vastly bigger to start with. I see nothing for the gap to break logistics on, there is a huge amount of restocking, resetting, adjustment of venues (because Paralympians are by definition differently abled in some significant way), and more.

@Nij I left aside spectators in my comment. Early September will be a nightmare from a transit perspective (all of the Paris region is back at the same time, and the ones who plan to leave have not done so yet), people who could have participated (not as spectators or sportsmen, but in the logistics) are more likely to not be available, etc.). As you mention TV - at least for Europe there will be much less viewing because of the end of vacation.

@Nij (cont'd) But OK, if there is no particular reason apart from logistics (which will work better, as opposed to what I was thinking) then this is absolutely fine -- I was looking for a formal reason.
